# What type of Gorgonzola cheese fungus/bacteria is this?

Tags: species-identification, food, mycology

I have purchased a gorgonzola cheese and it came with some orange/yellow fungus/bacteria in the cheese's surface. Anyone know what kind of fungus/bacteria it is, and if it's safe to eat?

[image: Picture of the fungus/bacteria]
[image: Picture of the fungus/bacteria]

Comment: I highly doubt if the nature of type of fungi can be identified just by looking at it.